# httpd dead but pid file exist | httpd dead but sudsys locked. Centos 6

Tags: web-server, http, centos6, httpd, httpd.conf

Centos 6 64bit clean install on VPS, any kind of package installed just trying to use the already installed httpd.

```
my case:    
[root@bucch ~]# service httpd status    
httpd is stopped    
[root@bucch ~]# service httpd start    
Starting httpd:                                           [  OK  ]    
[root@bucch ~]# service httpd status    
httpd dead but pid file exists     
[root@bucch ~]# rm -f /var/run/httpd/httpd.pid    
[root@bucch ~]# service httpd status    
httpd dead but subsys locked    
[root@bucch ~]# rm -f /var/lock/subsys/httpd    
[root@bucch ~]# service httpd status    
httpd is stopped    
[root@bucch ~]# tail -n 10 /var/log/httpd/error_log    
[Fri Oct 07 11:38:47 2016] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)    
[Fri Oct 07 11:38:47 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...    
[Fri Oct 07 11:38:47 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Oct 07 11:38:47 2016] [info] APR LDAP: Built with OpenLDAP LDAP SDK
[Fri Oct 07 11:38:47 2016] [info] LDAP: SSL support available
[Fri Oct 07 11:38:47 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations    
[Fri Oct 07 11:38:47 2016] [info] Server built: Jul 18 2016 15:24:00
[Fri Oct 07 11:38:47 2016] [debug] prefork.c(1028): AcceptMutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)    
[Fri Oct 07 11:38:47 2016] [debug] proxy_util.c(1909): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 4040 for worker proxy:reverse    
[Fri Oct 07 11:38:47 2016] [debug] proxy_util.c(2025): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 4040 for (*)
```

in the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf have this directive:

```
PidFile /var/run/httpd/httpd.pid
```

and in the /etc/sysconfig/httpd have this:

```
PIDFILE=/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid
```

in the /etc/sysconfig/iptables have:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT    
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

the directory /var/run/httpd have this kind of permission:

```
chmod a+rx
```

this is the output of netstat -plant that is the same before and after starting the httpd service

```
[root@bucch ~]# netstat -plant    
Active Internet connections (servers and established)    
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      693/sshd    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1875/sendmail    
tcp        0     64 212.8.250.64:22             x.x.x.x:49817               ESTABLISHED 3737/sshd    
tcp        0      0 212.8.250.64:22             x.x.x.x:49167               ESTABLISHED 3143/sshd    
tcp        0      0 212.8.250.64:22             x.x.x.x:46407               ESTABLISHED 4225/sshd    
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      693/sshd    
[root@bucch ~]#
```

i am going crazy! any suggest?

over there i got some info from
    `strace -f -o trace2.txt /etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd start`

```
[root@bucch ~]# tail -n 100 trace2.txt
6699  mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fdefce27000
6699  arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fdefce28700) = 0
6699  mprotect(0x7fdefc670000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
6699  mprotect(0x7fdefca00000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
6699  mprotect(0x7fdefcc10000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
6699  mprotect(0x7fdefce31000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
6699  munmap(0x7fdefce2a000, 21145)     = 0
6699  set_tid_address(0x7fdefce289d0)   = 6699
6699  set_robust_list(0x7fdefce289e0, 24) = 0
6699  futex(0x7ffe5442baac, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
6699  futex(0x7ffe5442baac, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, NULL, 7fdefce28700) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
6699  rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7fdefc45ecb0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fdefc4687e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
6699  rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7fdefc45ed40, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fdefc4687e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
6699  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
6699  getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=10240*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
6699  brk(0)                            = 0x12db000
6699  brk(0x12fc000)                    = 0x12fc000
6699  open("/var/lock/subsys/httpd", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666 <unfinished ...>
6698  <... open resumed> )              = 8
6698  fcntl(8, F_GETFD)                 = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
6698  fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
6698  write(8, "6698\n", 5)             = 5
6698  close(8)                          = 0
6698  semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, IPC_CREAT|0600) = 688130
6698  semctl(688130, 0, SETVAL, 0x1)    = 0
6698  geteuid()                         = 0
6698  semctl(688130, 0, IPC_SET, 0x7ffe08648870) = 0
6698  mmap(NULL, 19224, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc5ac649000
6698  rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {0x7fc5ac687050, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESETHAND, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
6698  rt_sigaction(SIGBUS, {0x7fc5ac687050, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESETHAND, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
6698  rt_sigaction(SIGABRT, {0x7fc5ac687050, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESETHAND, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
6698  rt_sigaction(SIGILL, {0x7fc5ac687050, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESETHAND, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
6698  rt_sigaction(SIGFPE, {0x7fc5ac687050, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESETHAND, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
6698  rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x7fc5ac691240, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
6698  rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x7fc5ac691240, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
6698  rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x7fc5ac691240, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
6698  rt_sigaction(SIGXCPU, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
6698  rt_sigaction(SIGXFSZ, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
6698  rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
6698  rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x7fc5ac691270, [HUP USR1], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
6698  rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {0x7fc5ac691270, [HUP USR1], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
6698  clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fc5ac641ab0) = 6700
6698  write(2, "[Fri Oct 07 20:31:44 2016] [noti"..., 104) = 104
6698  write(2, "[Fri Oct 07 20:31:44 2016] [info"..., 69) = 69
6698  write(2, "[Fri Oct 07 20:31:44 2016] [debu"..., 92) = 92
6698  wait4(-1, 0x7ffe086488ac, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
6698  select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0} <unfinished ...>
6700  set_robust_list(0x7fc5ac641ac0, 24) = 0
6700  rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x7fc5ac6920f0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, {0x7fc5ac691270, [HUP USR1], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, 8) = 0
6700  rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x7fc5ac6920f0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, {0x7fc5ac691240, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, 8) = 0
6700  rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, {0x7fc5ac691240, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, 8) = 0
6700  rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {0x7fc5ac691900, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, {0x7fc5ac691270, [HUP USR1], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fc5aaf2f7e0}, 8) = 0
6700  geteuid()                         = 0
6700  setgid(48)                        = 0
6700  open("/proc/sys/kernel/ngroups_max", O_RDONLY) = 8
6700  read(8, "65536\n", 31)            = 6
6700  close(8)                          = 0
6700  open("/etc/group", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 8
6700  fstat(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=532, ...}) = 0
6700  mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc5ac648000
6700  lseek(8, 0, SEEK_CUR)             = 0
6700  read(8, "root:x:0:\nbin:x:1:bin,daemon\ndae"..., 4096) = 532
6700  read(8, "", 4096)                 = 0
6700  close(8)                          = 0
6700  munmap(0x7fc5ac648000, 4096)      = 0
6700  setgroups(1, [48])                = 0
6700  geteuid()                         = 0
6700  setuid(48)                        = 0
6700  write(2, "[Fri Oct 07 20:31:44 2016] [debu"..., 127) = 127
6700  write(2, "[Fri Oct 07 20:31:45 2016] [debu"..., 123) = 123
6700  epoll_create1(EPOLL_CLOEXEC)      = 8
6700  epoll_ctl(8, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 3, {EPOLLIN, {u32=2915366168, u64=140487000651032}}) = 0
6700  accept4(3,  <unfinished ...>
6699  <... open resumed> )              = 3
6699  dup2(3, 0)                        = 0
6699  close(3)                          = 0
6699  utimensat(0, NULL, NULL, 0)       = 0
6699  close(0)                          = 0
6699  close(1)                          = 0
6699  close(2)                          = 0
6699  exit_group(0)                     = ?
6699  +++ exited with 0 +++
6690  <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 6699
6690  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
6690  --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=6699, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
6690  wait4(-1, 0x7ffd4819c31c, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
6690  rt_sigreturn()                    = 0
6690  rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f8437653660}, {0x43d610, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f8437653660}, 8) = 0
6690  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
6690  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
6690  read(255, "\nexit $RETVAL\n", 3488) = 14
6690  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
6690  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
6690  exit_group(0)                     = ?
6690  +++ exited with 0 +++
6698  <... select resumed> )            = 0 (Timeout)
6698  wait4(-1, 0x7ffe086488ac, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
6698  select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0} <unfinished ...>
6698  +++ killed by SIGKILL +++
6700  +++ killed by SIGKILL +++
```

Comment: What do your logs show?

Comment: Change the log level to `LogLevel debug`. Clear the error log. run `service httpd start` and then add the contents of the error log to your question.

Comment: it is already set to debug and on the top of the request can see the output of      tail -n 10 /var/log/httpd/error_log

Comment: What does "any kind of package installed just trying to use the already installed httpd." mean exactly?

Comment: Sorry, wanna mean: I just rebuild the VPS from the control panel than at fisrt login i added the iptables rule and after:     service httpd start    And it doesn't work..

Comment: `iptables` has nothing to do with your problem at this moment.  That will only affect whether anyone can get to your webserver once it's running correctly.

Comment: Port your _whole_ error log after clearing it and restarting `httpd` like @Unbeliever suggested.  10 lines may not be enough to see the problem.

Comment: made, but i got exactly the 10 linees posted before..

Comment: I have more important info about the error in the output of `strace -f -o trace.txt /etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd start` but i am not able to porst by phone now.

Comment: You are getting SIGKILL signals. Check for security software (such as SELinux) settings that prevent Apache from starting. Also, just to verify, try starting Apache with `apachectl start`. If anything is shown on the console add it to your question.

Comment: `[root@bucch selinux]# sestatus
SELinux status: disabled 
[root@bucch selinux]# apachectl start 
[root@bucch selinux]# service httpd status 
httpd dead but pid file exists`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sent a support request to the hosting provider and after 2 days they fixed the issue. The ticket had been closed with this message: 
*"Hello, the problem was on the node, we had to do a change on the node kernel."*

Now with the same configuration (and more packages) Apache is working perfect.
Thanks everybody anyway!

```
exit
```